# SQL update table values from a different table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-update, x-cart

I have 2 tables  xcart_products which has `productid , meta_description`  and many other fields . The 2nd table is  xcart_extra_field_values which has ( `productid fieldid and value` )

I need to copy the value of `fieldID = 1` of `xcart_extra_field_values`

into

the `meta_description` column of the `xcart_products` table where the `Productid` are same.

```
UPDATE `xcart_products` SET meta_description = ( SELECT value FROM
      xcart_extra_field_values WHERE fieldid = 1 AND
      xcart_extra_field_values.productid = xcart_products.productid ) 
WHERE 
    xcart_extra_field_values.productid = xcart_products.productid ;
```

I wrote the above SQL but i am getting an error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'xcart_extra_field_values.productid' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: you have to use join not inner select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work for you:

```
UPDATE `xcart_products`, `xcart_extra_field_values` SET xcart_products.meta_description = xcart_extra_field_values.value 
WHERE
xcart_extra_field_values.fieldid = 1
AND
xcart_products.productid = xcart_extra_field_values.productid
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to the second table name to your query, because it is used in the query, even though you are not changing any data in it.

UPDATE xcart_products, xcart_extra_field_values

Answer (score 1):

You could use the multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax to join the tables instead:

```
UPDATE xcart_products JOIN xcart_extra_field_values USING (productid)
SET    xcart_products.meta_description = xcart_extra_field_values.value
WHERE  xcart_extra_field_values.fieldid = 1;
```